# message id from GetResultData

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I cannot seem to get or store the id of the post message I create. I am using this code to post a message:

```
Try

        Dim fb = New FacebookClient(_accessToken)

        AddHandler fb.PostCompleted, Function(o, e)
                                         If (e.Cancelled) Then

                                         ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
                                             MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
                                         Else
                                             Dim result As Object = e.GetResultData()
                                             _lastMessageId = result.Id
                                         End If
                                         Return MessageBox.Show("Message Posted successfully")
                                     End Function

        Dim parameters As Object = New ExpandoObject()
        parameters.message = TextBox1.Text
        fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters)

        MsgBox("This is the last message id " & _lastMessageId)

    Catch ex As FacebookApiException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I just want to store the posted id so I can delete it later.

Here is the working code that i came up with thanks to prabir

```
  Dim fb = New FacebookClient(_accessToken)

    Dim parameters As Object = New ExpandoObject()
    parameters.message = "Testing"

    Dim task = fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters)

    task.ContinueWith(Function(t)

                          If t.Exception Is Nothing Then

                              Dim result As Object = t.Result
                              _lastMessageId = result.id

                          Else

                              MsgBox("error occurred")

                          End If

                          Return t.Result

                      End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is c# code which might help you get started with it.

Since you are using XTaskAsync methods use ContinueWith instead of PostCompleted.

```
fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters)
  .ContinueWith(t= > {
    if(!t.IsFaulted) {
      dynamic result = t.Result;
    }
  });
```

XTaskAsync methods returns `Task<object>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.i have it working now am not quite sure if its 100% yet but it does work. i can seem to post the working code here but ill keep trying as it may help someone else.again thanks